# How to adjust coordinates of duplicated layers on QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, coordinates

I am having an issue with QGIS.

There are two layers (opaque green and brighter green) which are in different positions but are showing the same coordinates (tables below).

How do I update layer coordinates?

OBS.: those layers were drawn based on an orthomosaic and one layer is a moved duplication of the other.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the **field calculator** and select **update existing field**, select field `x_min`

Enter the expression `x_min($geometry)`, then apply.

Do the equivalent for the other fields, and it should all be updated.